# How to set uareu digitalpersona fingerprint format to ansi378-2004 or ISO19794-2005

Tags: java, fingerprint, biometrics

I'm new to fingerprint implementation and am working on a project that requires the use of biometrics of which I chose the DigitalPersona fingerprint devices.

I tested with their sample code for java and everything seem to work, but I need the fingerprint templates in ANSI 378 standard format which the device is said to support.

How can I do this? The fingerprint device is uareu 4500.

Comment: Please share more info: SDK used, code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing code from you, but maybe you could try something like this:

```
Fmd fmd = UareUGlobal.GetEngine().CreateFmd(fid, 
         Fid.Format.ANSI_381_2004);
```

Comment: Work like charm using SDK v2.3, although i was using SDK v1.6 when i wrote this post.